# Google material ripple button effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have "translated" [this example built with jQuery](http://codepen.io/KrisOlszewski/pen/Dnktj) in vanilla JavaScript, but I'd like to know if there are better ways to do it.

The jQuery version uses `offset()` function and `on()` for every events, while I've used this function for offset:

```
function offset(elt) {
    var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect(), bodyElt = document.body;
    return {
        top: rect.top + bodyElt .scrollTop,
        left: rect.left + bodyElt .scrollLeft
    }
}
```

and this one to prefix `AnimationEnd` event :

```
var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];
function prefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
        if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

From this [sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/)

My entire code is visible [here at Codepen](http://codepen.io/AlexanderDom/pen/gbevVo).

Otherwise, here is my example code:

**HTML**

```html
<button>
  <span class="ripples">
    <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
  </span>Test
</button>
<button>
  <span class="ripples">
    <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
  </span>Test
</button>
<button>
  <span class="ripples">
    <span class="ripples-circle"></span>
  </span>Test
</button>
```

**SCSS (without prefixes):**

```html
button {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-style:solid;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all .25s ease;

    &:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: darken(gray, 5%);
    }
    }

    .ripples {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;

    &.is-active {
        .ripples-circle {
            animation: ripples .4s ease-in;
        }
    }

    .ripples-circle {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
}

@keyframes ripples {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 200%;
        padding-bottom: 200%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```html
(function(window, document, undefined){
    'use strict';
    //http://www.debray-jerome.fr/js-performance-la-fonction-offset-de-jquery-vs-vanilla-javascript-23.html
    function offset(elt) {
        var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect(), bodyElt = document.body;
        return {
            top: rect.top + bodyElt .scrollTop,
            left: rect.left + bodyElt .scrollLeft
        }
    }

  //http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/

    var pfx = ["webkit", "moz", "MS", "o", ""];
    function prefixedEvent(element, type, callback) {
        for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
            if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
            element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
        }
    }

    var ripples = document.querySelectorAll('.ripples');
    for(var i=0; i < ripples.length;i++ ){
         ripples[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
            var rippleThis = this;
            var parentOffset = offset(rippleThis.parentNode);
            var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
            var y = e.pageY + parentOffset.top;
            var j;
            var childrenLength = rippleThis.childNodes.length;
            var targetChild;
            for(j = 0; j < childrenLength; j++){
              if(rippleThis.childNodes[j].className == 'ripples-circle') targetChild = rippleThis.childNodes[j];
            }

            targetChild.style.top = y + 'px';
            targetChild.style.left = x + 'px';

            rippleThis.className = 'ripples is-active';
        }, false);
        prefixedEvent(ripples[i], "AnimationEnd", function(e){
            e.currentTarget.className = 'ripples';
        });
    }

})(window, document);
```

Answer (score 3):

Some things that I would do differently in this for loop

> ```
> for(var i=0; i < ripples.length;i++ ){
>      ripples[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
>         var rippleThis = this;
>         var parentOffset = offset(rippleThis.parentNode);
>         var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
>         var y = e.pageY + parentOffset.top;
>         var j;
>         var childrenLength = rippleThis.childNodes.length;
>         var targetChild;
>         for(j = 0; j < childrenLength; j++){
>           if(rippleThis.childNodes[j].className == 'ripples-circle') targetChild = rippleThis.childNodes[j];
>         }
>
>         targetChild.style.top = y + 'px';
>         targetChild.style.left = x + 'px';
>
>         rippleThis.className = 'ripples is-active';
>     }, false);
>     prefixedEvent(ripples[i], "AnimationEnd", function(e){
>         e.currentTarget.className = 'ripples';
>     });
> }
> ```

First thing I saw was that you created an increment variable outside of the for loop declaration,  that just makes things a little messy, there isn't any reason for `var j;` outside of the for loop.

`rippleThis` isn't a good variable name, I would name this variable `thisRipple` because it is literally this ripple object.

You should also give your code some breathing room, like in the for loop declaration

`var i = 0; i < ripples.length; i++`  looks better than `var i=0; i < ripples.length;i++`

After all these changes it would look like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < ripples.length; i++ ){
    ripples[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var thisRipple = this;
        var parentOffset = offset(thisRipple.parentNode);
        var x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var y = e.pageY + parentOffset.top;
        var childrenLength = thisRipple.childNodes.length;
        var targetChild;
        for(var j = 0; j < childrenLength; j++){
            if(thisRipple.childNodes[j].className == 'ripples-circle') targetChild = thisRipple.childNodes[j];
        }

        targetChild.style.top = y + 'px';
        targetChild.style.left = x + 'px';

        thisRipple.className = 'ripples is-active';
    }, false);
    prefixedEvent(ripples[i], "AnimationEnd", function(e){
        e.currentTarget.className = 'ripples';
    });
}
```